# French character displaying wrong in email

Tags: html, email, asp-classic

When mail is sent with French characters, they are displaying incorrectly in the mail body.

I have set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in my HTML page.

I have sent my html page in mail body, but, when I run the HTML page in a browser, it displays correctly.

Comment: Please provide a repro of your HTML so that we can see what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand

Comment: Please post an example of actual HTML e-mail body (a complete HTML document, preferably small) that illustrates the problem. Also include the e-mail message headers and specify how an e-mail program (which?) displays the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done using set charcter set for mail sender.

such as

```
Mail.TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp

Since many countries use characters which are not a part of ASCII, the default character-set for modern browsers is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is better for browser. but in mail body it's not working.